# Tar and nails failing on roof boot. How to fix?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, roofing, shingles

The nails fastening my roof boot to the shingles are rusting, and the tar around the nails looks like it’s failing as well.

What would be the proper steps to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What _was_ there covering some of the shingles preventing them from fading?

Comment: @FreeMan We sprayed the boot black, and sprayed part of the shingles too.

Comment: Do you have evidence for this other than the mild corrosion of one nail in an exposed situation? This doesn't look like a problem to me. I see nothing "failing".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the nails are still secure, then just seal over them with some sealant.

If the nails are loose, you'll want to replace them first.